# image uploaded to database but unable to display the image

Tags: sql, database, image

Im using the simpleform to upload the file image

```
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Photo</td>
    <td><input type="file"size="30" name="photo" /></td>
  </tr>
```

then here is my php file..Im using mysql_fetch_array
row[6] is my photo...

```
    // retrieves a row data and returns it as an associative array
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<table border='1' align='center' class='table_background'>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left' width=100>UserName=</td>
                            <td align='left' width='400'></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left' width=100>Title=</td>
                            <td align='left' width='400'>$row[1]</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left'width=100>Category=</td>
                            <td align='left'width='400'>$row[2]</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left'width=100>Description=</td>
                            <td align='left'width='400'>$row[3]</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left'width=100>State=</td>
                            <td align='left'width='400'>$row[4]</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left'width=100>Photo=</td>
                            <td align='left'width='400'>$row[5]</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align='left'width=100>Date=</td>
                            <td align='left'width='200'>$row[6]</td>
                        </tr>

                    <br>

            }           
                    <br>
                    <br>
        </table>";

        }
```

In my database I use Blob as the type of image ... the image is successful upload to my database
but just display the image file name...

Answer (score 0):

blob is a string so you have to display id a bit different

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row[6] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: Hi thanks... but its show me   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'data' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\GoGreen\displayitem.php on line 66                     when Im using this code         <td align='left'width='200'><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,base64_encode( $row[6] )/>';